# SQL query not being executed from bash script

Tags: bash, sh, sqlplus

I have the following function currently, I know the outputted query works when I run it manually through the GUI SQL Client, but it doesnt work from Bash...
I tried everything I could think of and googled with what keywords I could think about..

```
AssignChunksToDocs()
{
TEST="set heading off;
        set trim on;
        DECLARE
        i number;

        BEGIN
                i := 1;


                while i<=$CHUNK_AMOUNT LOOP
                  UPDATE TABLE T SET T.CHUNK_NUM = i
                  WHERE T.CHUNK_NUM IS NULL
                  AND ROWNUM <=$DOCS_PER_CHUNK;
                  i := i+1;
                END LOOP;
        i := i-1;
        -- Deal with the remainder
        UPDATE TABLE T SET T.CHUNK_NUM = i
        WHERE T.CHUNK_NUM IS NULL;

        end;"

        sqlplus -s $CONSTR<<ENDOFSQL
        set heading off;
        set trim on;
        DECLARE
        i number;

        BEGIN
                i := 1;


                while i<=$CHUNK_AMOUNT LOOP
                  UPDATE TABLE T SET T.CHUNK_NUM = i
                  WHERE T.CHUNK_NUM IS NULL
                  AND ROWNUM <=$DOCS_PER_CHUNK;
                  i := i+1;
                END LOOP;
        i := i-1;
        -- Deal with the remainder
        UPDATE TABLE T SET T.CHUNK_NUM = i
        WHERE T.CHUNK_NUM IS NULL;

        end;
ENDOFSQL

ERRORCODE=$?
if [ $ERRORCODE != 0 ]
then
  echo "********************"
  echo "ERROR: The SQL Plus Command Failed. ErrorCode: $ERRORCODE"
else
  echo "********************"
  echo "SQL Plus Successfully Ran. ErrorCode: $ERRORCODE"
fi

}
```

When I run it (with -x in shebang), I get the following snippet:

```
+ AssignChunksToDocs
+ TEST='set heading off;
        set trim on;
        DECLARE
        i number;

        BEGIN
                i := 1;


                while i<=
        64 LOOP
                  UPDATE TABLE T SET T.CHUNK_NUM = i
                  WHERE T.CHUNK_NUM IS NULL
                  AND ROWNUM <=3;
                  i := i+1;
                END LOOP;
        i := i-1;
        -- Deal with the remainder
        UPDATE TABLE T SET T.CHUNK_NUM = i
        WHERE T.CHUNK_NUM IS NULL;

        end;'
+ sqlplus -s dbuser/dbpass@hostname/sidname
+ ERRORCODE=0
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ echo '********************'
********************
+ echo 'SQL Plus Successfully Ran. ErrorCode: 0'
SQL Plus Successfully Ran. ErrorCode: 0
```

Same happens for manual test of the query in terminal command line, followed by manual paste of << SQL ... SQL block.

Please help :)

Comment: Use `if [ $ERRORCODE -ne 0 ]` for comparing integers.

Comment: Thanks, that is a small fix but not my main problem.

Comment: There's something I'm not getting; The script says the SQL ran successfully. Why do you say it doesn't?

Comment: @Kusalananda: Its just an echo when script exits with error code 0, in this case it is misleading. I do not believe it has ran, since nothing happend - the values are still NULL, but I know for fact this query works when I run it manually in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have just copied the output in TEST and ran manually again - entries were changed from NULL.. so yeah, this confirms the query was not executed from command line.

Comment: Have you used TABs or spaces at the starts of the lines?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Actually I have spaces  and tabs in the SQL query to keep it in readable form, why?

Comment: Maybe try with TABs only.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just tried converting the few spaces to tabs - no effect.

Comment: Has your `$CHUNK_AMOUNT` got a CR/LF in it at the start? It has come out on a new line in the interpreted script.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes it has, but I had problems cleaning it up for some reason... although it doesn't seem to affect the query in any way. I would love to clean it up, if you know how?

Comment: Sure, `CHUNK_AMOUNT=$(tr -d '\r\n' <<< $CHUNK_AMOUNT)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a missing `COMMIT;` statement!
In the future, in case of a weird situation like that with no errors but nothing apparent happening in the DB, ask the DBA to look for table locks!

Twice they were the cause of it not working for missing COMMIT; after every update statement.